# Cucumber-scala BDD test with maven

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber

I am trying cucumber BDD tests for my scala maven project, I tried to add dependencies upon which the jars are added in the intellij ,but due to unknown reason I am not able to import the cucumber packages by `import` statements.
MY POM

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.cuke</groupId>
        <artifactId>xdq</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </parent>
   <artifactId>cuke-test</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-native_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.exadatum</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-generator</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-azkaban-job-artifact</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.job</file>
                                    <type>job</type>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.exadatum.sensorium.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>template-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-azkaban-job-file</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputFileName>${project.artifactId}.job</outputFileName>
                            <template>azkaban-job.vm</template>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>module-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>

                                <descriptor>
                                    ${multi.module.project.root.dir}/libraries/common/src/main/resources/assemblies/module-tar-assembly.xml
                                </descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <!--<tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>-->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <checkMultipleScalaVersions>false</checkMultipleScalaVersions>
                    <recompileMode>modified-only</recompileMode>
                    <useZincServer>false</useZincServer>
                    <scalaVersion>2.11.8</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Let me know where am I doing things wrong
I tried creating the scala class and extending with `ScalaDsl` but it wont resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created an empty scala project and added maven. Copied your pom.xml and removed `<parent><\parent>` as well as `<artifactId>cuke-test</artifactId>`. There are other dependency problems but then again, I don't know the structure of you project.

After this I created a class:

```
import cucumber.api.scala.ScalaDsl

class TestClass extends ScalaDsl {

}
```

and the import works.

Have a look [here](https://github.com/jecklgamis/cucumber-jvm-scala-example/blob/master/pom.xml#L8) for an example project / pom.xml and [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) for more info about `<parent>` and pom.

Hope you get it working.